# How to implement a simple Drag/Drop pattern component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new to React.js, what I want to implement is a drag drop component (let us call it DDCom):

DDCom can drag (but not move the original one, more like a clone and that clone move with mouse), and that clone can only drop to other DDCom area (when drag start, each DDCom will show a highlight background area to indicate the drop area)

I really have no idea how to implement this in React.js, could anyone give any code example for this ( or some explanation about how to structure this with FLUX pattern)? Most posts point to React DnD, but it seems so big and hard to understand, what I want is a simple clear work flow of implementation.

Comment: There is react-dnd from one of the authors of redux: https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd

Comment: A simple HTML 5 solution is available. Here is the implementation in reactJS - https://youtu.be/z2nHLfiiKBA

Answer (score 0):

You might find https://github.com/Khan/react-components/tree/master/examples useful, within the  react components / examples there is a drag drop example.
or http://react.rocks/tag/Drag_Drop
Also looked at React DnD but I agree its hard to wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dargula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula).
Its simple and clear and has a react wrapper, [react-dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/react-dragula)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy I think with https://github.com/peterh32/react-drag-drop-container

```
<DragDropContainer targetKey="DDCom" >
    <div>Drag Me!</div>
</DragDropContainer>

<DropTarget targetKey="DDCom" >
    <p>I'm a valid drop target for the object above since we both have the same targetKey!</p>
</DropTarget>
```

If you put `dragClone={true}` in the DragDropContainer, it will drag a copy as you describe.

Then add an `onHit` event handler in DropTarget to do what you want when the item is dropped on it.

Works on mouse and touchscreens too.

Answer (score 0):

I used the react dropzone package - https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone. There is even support for material ui.